# if cell has text="yes" then for every yes in whole column SUM (200 for every Yes)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to calculate the following:-

if cell has text="yes" then for every yes in whole column SUM (200 for every Yes)

Answer (score 0):

This formula answers your question, however I suspect you excluded something to make it more complex.

```
=if(B1="Yes",countif(B:B,"Yes")*200,"")
```

[image]

Comment: =IF('Form Responses 4'!E2:E200="Yes","Jimmy",countif('Form Responses 4'!E2:E200,"Yes")*200,"") this is giving me an error

Comment: this is also something i came up with :-
=SUMIF('Form Responses 4'!B2:B100,"Jimmy",SUMIF('Form Responses 4'!E2:E100,"Yes", 200))

Comment: =if('Form Responses 4'!E2:E201="Yes",countif('Form Responses 4'!E2:E201,"Yes")*200,"") this is working but i want to add another condition to it "if G2:G200="jimmy"